# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS -- Repeat Keys only works on certain keys after using Dvorak-Qwerty remap script

Tags: drivers, keyboard

Repeat keys works for space-bar, backspace, enter, but not any character keys. This happened after waking from hibernate. Repeat keys are certainly turned on, its on in the settings GUI, its on in `xset`, I have no `peaq_wmi` module to blacklist as is the common solution to this problem.

If I use the on screen keyboard all keys repeat as expected. It also doesn't seem to be purely a hardware issue as repeat keys for all keys works in BIOS, but not in the login screen, nor the desktop of Ubuntu.

Other ideas that haven't worked:

Reinstalling `xorg-input-kbd`

I'm certain its a driver issue but not certain how to proceed without reinstalling. I have performed `apt update && apt upgrade` already.

Answer (score 0):

This makes for a bad post, but still may be helpful. Upon investigating I realized the culprit was a custom keyboard layout config installation.

https://github.com/ZeptByteS/dvorak-qwerty

Only upon running:

`tar -xvzf xkb-backup.tar.gz`

in the script directory (that archive was made during install and restores the files it changes in their proper location), removing any keyboard layouts that were a part of it (in the Regions and Languages section of settings) then restarting the PC was the issue resolved.

Installing a custom keyboard layout is certainly the culprit, and one perhaps only the installer could detect, so its a bit unfair I get to answer, but maybe this is helpful to someone.